# how to replace vertex buffer in webGL

Tags: javascript, webgl

I want to replace a vertex buffer with another completely different vertex buffer, different size and values, it will not get replaced every frame.

```
gl.deleteBuffer(vertexBuffer);
vertexBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBuffer);
gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, vArray, gl.STATIC_DRAW);
```

I am using that code to replace it, I don't think it is the correct way because I am getting:

```
GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_OPERATION : glDrawArrays: attempt to render with no buffer attached to enabled attribute 1
```

I don't know if this is related to the error but I am rendering using the vertex buffer when I replace it.